# Cordova: Sqlite isnt storing my data

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm new to hybrid mobile application development. I'm building a simple application where I want to register users and use the same same credentials in to sign in. The problem I'm facing is that while I'm inserting records in the sqlite database it's not storing my data. If I restart my application it wont allow me to use the previously inserted information.
I'm using Cordova for native wrapping, Graphite as my IDE and sqlite as my database.

This is my register.js file

```
var db;
var dbCreated = false;

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
 vScrollbar : false,
 hScrollbar : false,
 hScroll : false
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("psw").value;

    db = window.openDatabase("RegistrationDB", "1.0", "Registration", 200000);

    if (dbCreated){

    } else{
        db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
    }

}

function populateDB(tx) {

 var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration ( "
   + "firstName VARCHAR(50), " + "lastName VARCHAR(50), "
   + "age INTEGER, " + "username VARCHAR(50), "
   + "password VARCHAR(200))";
 tx.executeSql(sql);
 var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var lname =  document.getElementById("lname").value;
 var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
 var uname =document.getElementById("username").value;
 var pwrd = document.getElementById("psw").value;
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Registration (firstname,lastname,age,username,password) VALUES ('"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"' , "+ age+", '"+ uname +"','"+ pwrd +"' )");

}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
 alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function populateDB_success() {
 dbCreated = true;

 alert("Successfully inserted");
  //window.location="file:///MyApp/MyApp/login.html"
    window.location = "./login.html"
}

    var db;
var dbCreated = false;

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
 vScrollbar : false,
 hScrollbar : false,
 hScroll : false
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("psw").value;

    db = window.openDatabase("RegistrationDB", "1.0", "Registration", 200000);

    if (dbCreated){

    } else{
        db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
    }

}

function populateDB(tx) {

 var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration ( "
   + "firstName VARCHAR(50), " + "lastName VARCHAR(50), "
   + "age INTEGER, " + "username VARCHAR(50), "
   + "password VARCHAR(200))";
 tx.executeSql(sql);
 var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var lname =  document.getElementById("lname").value;
 var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
 var uname =document.getElementById("username").value;
 var pwrd = document.getElementById("psw").value;
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Registration (firstname,lastname,age,username,password) VALUES ('"+ fname +"','"+ lname +"' , "+ age+", '"+ uname +"','"+ pwrd +"' )");

}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
 alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function populateDB_success() {
 dbCreated = true;

 alert("Successfully inserted");
  //window.location="file:///MyApp/MyApp/login.html"
    window.location = "./login.html"
}
```

This is my login.js

```
var db;
var dbCreated = false;

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
 vScrollbar : false,
 hScrollbar : false,
 hScroll : false
});
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
 db = window.openDatabase("RegistrationDB", "1.0", "Registration", 200000);
 if (dbCreated)
  {
      // created
  }

 else{
 db.transaction(getregistdata, transaction_error);
 }
}

function getregistdata(tx){

  var sql = "select username, password from Registration";
  tx.executeSql(sql, [], getlogin_success);
}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
 alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function getlogin_success(tx, results){
   var len = results.rows.length;
   for (var i=0; i< len; i++) { 
    var employee = results.rows.item(i);
    var username=document. getElementById("username").value;
    var password=document. getElementById("psw").value;
    var uname=employee.username;
    var pasw=employee.password;
    alert(username);
    alert(password);
    if(username == uname && password == pasw){
     alert("Login Success");
     break;
    }
    else{
        var status=1;
     }
   }

   if(status == 1)
    {
       alert("login failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you debug this to find out "its not saving data"? are the values of input fields `undefined`? Did you paste register.js twice in the question?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally did copied register.js twice. When I restart my app in emulator and use the same credentials as i did earlier to sign in it gives me the alert 'login failed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase` rather than `window.openDatabase`:

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'RegistrationDB', location: 'default'});
```

And make sure you have installed sqlite plugin with cordova